# Gemfire NoAvailableServerException when using a local cache

Tags: exception, spring-data, gemfire

I have dynamic configurations that will either use a server cache or a local cache for gemfire dao objects.
When I call:

```
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);
        results = (SelectResults) query.execute();
```

I am getting a "NoAvailableServerException" when configured for a local cache.  If I configure for an actual Gemfire Server, everything is working.
If I change the above to use the region query:

```
results = region.query(queryString);
```

the code will work on the local cache:
However, I do not want to change the original code and want to take advantage of QueryService when possible.  I configured my local cache with:

```
<gfe:client-cache id="cache" />
```

I configured my server cache with a pool:

```
<gfe:client-cache id="dev-client-cache" pool-name="dev-pool" pdx-read-serialized="false" pdx-serializer-ref="pdxAutoSerializer" />
```

These statements were run all in line with a local cache.  The region.query will work and return the proper data.  The query.execute will fail with the NoAvailableServerException.

```
SelectResults<AA> results
Region<Object, Object> region = getCache().getRegion(AA.class.getSimpleName());
results = region.query(queryString);
QueryService queryService = getCache().getQueryService();
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);
results = (SelectResults) query.execute();
```

Is there something I am missing to get QueryService working on my local cache?

Answer (score 0):

By default the `QueryService` used by the `ClientCache` will try to execute the query on any available servers, unless instructed to do otherwise. Can you post the snippet of code showing how you are constructing/obtaining the actual `QueryService` instance?, have you tried executing the query using the `QueryService` returned by `ClientCache.getLocalQueryService()`?.
Cheers.

Comment: These statements were run all in line with a local cache.  The region.query will work and return the proper data.  The query.execute will fail with the NoAvailableServerException.

SelectResults<AA> results
Region<Object, Object> region = getCache().getRegion(AA.class.getSimpleName());
results = region.query(queryString);
QueryService queryService = getCache().getQueryService();
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);
results = (SelectResults) query.execute();

Comment: Hey Greg, as I stated above, the `QueryService` returned by `Cache.getQueryService()` will automatically try to execute the queries on the server side, you should use `Cache.getLocalQueryService()` instead. Please give it a try and let me know how it goes.